# Training LSTM model in R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am attempting to train a LSMT model in R.

I need the Call Counts predicted for every hour for the next couple of months.

I need the call_day_of_week_name,call_month, Calls Count, call_year variables to influence the prediction to predict the call count for every hour for the next two months.

I needed some assistance from chatGPT as I am not as experienced in R. At first I got the error

Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1,1,1)
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

Which I realised to be coming from this part of the loop:

```
  if (date == as.Date("2023-08-28")) {
    predicted_data[i, 3:length(time_slots) + 2] <- NA  # Assign NA for the time slots on the bank holiday
  } else {
    # Filter historic data for the current date
    ##current_data <- filtered_data[filtered_data$call_day_of_week_name == weekdays(date) &
                                   ##filtered_data$call_month == as.integer(format(date, "%m")) 
    #&
                                   ##filtered_data$call_year == as.integer(format(date, "%Y"))
    #, ]
```

as far as I understand. ChatGPT was trying to filter it out by the existing dates in the historic data. If my understanding serves me correctly, the dates won't bring back anything anyway because we are forecasting for future dates, hence, the future dates won't be visible in the historic data.

So I have now commented out that part of the filtering. It is clear from my script where I have made the changes as I have added comments for my own reference.

Now the error says this instead

Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 113472 into shape (1,1,1)
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

What is it that I need to do fit this model to the required dimensions.

Thank you ever so much. Here is all the code:

```
 # Iterate over the date range ####for loop starts here
    for (i in 1:length(dates)) {     
      date <- dates[i]
      
      # Check if it is a bank holiday (August 28, 2023) and handle predictions differently
      if (date == as.Date("2023-08-28")) {
        predicted_data[i, 3:length(time_slots) + 2] <- NA  # Assign NA for the time slots on the bank holiday
      } else {
        # Filter historic data for the current date
        ##current_data <- filtered_data[filtered_data$call_day_of_week_name == weekdays(date) &
                                       ##filtered_data$call_month == as.integer(format(date, "%m")) 
        #&
                                       ##filtered_data$call_year == as.integer(format(date, "%Y"))
        #, ]
    
        ##print(dim(current_data))
        ##print(head(current_data))
        
        # Prepare the data for LSTM training
        x_train <- filtered_data[, "call_hour"] ###changed this from current_data (now filters removed at top) to filtered_data
        y_train <- filtered_data[, "Calls Count"]  ###changed this from current_data (now filters removed at top) to filtered_data
        
        # Normalize the data (if needed)
        # Apply any required data preprocessing steps (e.g., scaling, normalization, encoding, etc.)
        
        # Reshape the data for LSTM training
        x_train <- array_reshape(x_train, dim = c(length(x_train), 1, 1)) ## think the problem might be here
        
        # Build and train the LSTM model
        model <- keras::keras_model_sequential()
        model %>%
          layer_lstm(units = 64, input_shape = c(1, 1)) %>%
          layer_dense(units = 1)
        
        model %>% compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
        model %>% fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
        
        # Perform predictions for the time slots
        predictions <- model %>% predict(x_train)
        
        # Store the predictions in the corresponding time slots of the predicted_data dataframe
        predicted_data[i, 3:length(time_slots) + 2] <- predictions
      }
    }    
    ######for loop ends here
```

Comment: Hi Vern, your question will likely gain more feedback if you put in the effort to distill a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ ).

Comment: Hi @I_O, I am a little unsure on how to edit this post. I have provided the error messages, pointed to the part of the code where I think the problem is. I have also displayed all the code that the loop contains to provide extra clarity. I am not disputing anything you are saying. I am obviously being stupid. Can you please advise on what it is that needs to be improved on this post? I generally do need some advice so could do with the extra feed back. Thanking you :)

Comment: Honestly, there's nothing stupid to it! :-) From what I grasp (without experience with ML), the issue has to do with `shape`ing the array as you pointed out. To test this, though, others would need to generate a data set hopefully representative of your `filtered_data` (why not paste the output of `dput(head(filtered_data))` or a minimal sufficient sample thereof? In the process, check out function `shape` (https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guides/keras/sequential_model#specifying-the-input-shape-in-advance) which even might solve the problem.  If not, others can have a go at it right away.

Comment: Hi @I_O, 

I have read the blog.

Here is what the dput head returns:

structure(list(`Calls Count` = c(4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1), call_day_of_week_name = c("Friday", 
"Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"), call_month = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), call_year = c("2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021"), call_hour = c(9, 10, 12, 11, 14, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


Many thanks for your advice.

I am still stuck :( with this reshaping an array.

Comment: Apparently you first need to `unlist` x_train (which is a list) of length 1, not 6 - use `nrow` instead: `x_train <- array_reshape(unlist(x_train), dim = c(nrow(x_train), 1, 1))`. However, this only takes the hurdle of reshaping x_train. The subsequent code throws Keras-specific (I think) errors which I unfortunately can't help with.